# How do I split the text into two lines when using ncangle and ncput?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

How do I split text into two lines in an arc?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](10,6)
\rput(2,1){\Rnode{r1}{}}
\rput(2,5){\Rnode{r2}{}}
\ncangle[angleA=180, angleB=180, arm=1, linearc=0.5, arrows=->]{r1}{r2}\ncput*{\small test, test2}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I have two rnodes and connect them with an `ncangle` and with `\ncput` i put a text in the arc. Here it prints `test, test2` but i would like to have two lines, such `test` is in line 1 and `test2` in a second line directly under `test`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,6)
\pnodes(2,1){r1}(2,5){r2}
\ncangle[angleA=180,angleB=180,arm=1,linearc=0.5,arrows=->]{r1}{r2}
\ncput*{\small\shortstack{t1\\test2}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node} % Thanks to ArtificialStupidity
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](10,6)
\rput(2,1){\Rnode{r1}{}}
\rput(2,5){\Rnode{r2}{}}
\ncangle[angleA=180, angleB=180, arm=1, linearc=0.5,
arrows=->]{r1}{r2}\ncput*{\small\begin{tabular}{c}
test\\ test2
\end{tabular}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The nice thing about pstricks and other packages like asymptote and tikz is that you can use all the LaTeX commands for annotations and so on.

Comment: You don't need to load all packages, `pst-node` is enough in this case.

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity You're right.